# Combine two tables or keep them separate?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

**Structure**

```
TableA (each row in TableA can map to one or more row in circle)
    Id
    Name

TableB (each row in TableB can map to only one row in TableA)
    Id
    TableAId
    UniqueValue
```

**Example Data**

```
TableA
    1,Sooprise

TableB
    1,1,something
    2,1,somethingElse
```

So in this case, "UniqueValue" can only associate themselves to one row in TableA.  Would it make more sense to combine the tables?

**Structure**

```
TableC
    Id
    Name
    UniqueValue
```

**Example Data**

```
TableC
    1,Sooprise,something
    2,Sooprise,somethingElse
```

I'm leaning more towards the first choice, but since there is a one to one mapping from B to A, these tables *can* be combined.  I do understand that combining the tables would result in a data redundancy (Name) but maybe there can be exceptions made for not using two relational tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd keep the two tables separated.
And I would create a view to get the next structure if needed.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "create a view to get the next structure if needed"?  Thanks! :)

Comment: I would create something like that:

 `CREATE VIEW DenormalizedView AS SELECT TableB.Id, TableA.Id, TableA.Name, TableB.UniqueValue FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Id=TableB.Name`

Comment: This way, I keep a "normalized" structure for my data and I have a way to query some kind of "denormalized" view of my data (to ease further developments).

Answer (score 1):

I think the choice will be determined by what the tables are going to be used for.  Two tables are probably the better design if you look at database space (Which may not be a concern), and if you are concerned about updated.  (if 1,Sooprise becomes 1,Sooprise_New do you want to update all of the records in table B, or do you want the values to remain 1,Sooprise for some entries)?

I have found that for future changes in data structures its best to keep twp tables

Comment: In my case, if Sooprise became Sooprise_New, the change would go in effect for all Sooprise values.

Comment: Since you would want the changes to cascade to all of the related records in the related data, I think you will prefer having two tables then.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. What are the tables used for? If you find yourself needing data from multiple relational tables at the same time, then it's probably a good idea to join them. If their use is largely separate and you feel separate tables enhance clarity, then keep them separate.